# Script apagando outros elementos do html

Tags: jquery

Estou tentando colocar uma mensagem de campo requerido, no momento só consigo colocar em um input, a ideia é colocar em todos e ao sofre a ação de um click na mensagem, a tag que é criada dinamicamente será apagada.

Com o script abaixo, ao clicar dentro de um input e depois dar um click fora da caixa do input sem ter preenchido nada, irá aparece a mensagem de campo requerido e ao dar um click nessa mensagem, a mesma é apagada.

Porém, se eu clica em algum campo ainda com a mensagem ativa, todos os elementos que forem clicados serão apagados.

```
$('#nome').blur(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  //esse if evita ficar aparecendo varias mensagens
  if($('.triangulo').length){
    return;
}
// esse if adiciona a tag p com o conteúdo e atributos
if($(this).val().length <= 0){
  var p = $("<p>").text("Campo obrigatório").attr("class", "triangulo").addClass('caixa').attr("id","remover");
  var nome = $("form");
  nome.append(p);
}
});
//evento de click para remover a mensagem
$('form').click(function(e){
 var removerCampoRequerido = $("p").attr('id');
 if("remover" == removerCampoRequerido){
  e.target.remove();
}
});
```

O formulário

```
<form id="formulario">
 <div id="tag" style="width:60%; margin:0 auto">
  <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
   <input name="nome" type="text" placeholder="Nome" id="nome" class="trazer-nome">

  <label for="cpf">CPF:</label>
   <input name="cpf" type="text" placeholder="CPF" id="cpf">

  <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
   <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email">
</form>
```

Os estilos para compor a mensagem

```
<style>
  .caixa {
    background:blue;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1px;
    position: relative;
    width: 130px;
    opacity: 0.70;
    margin: -30px 0 0 370px;
  }
  .triangulo:before {
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: blue;
    content: "";
    left: 20px;
    top: -20px;
    position: absolute;
  }
</style>
```

Estou fazendo o uso do jquery.

Comment: Não seria melhor criar uma função para esconder a mensagem, e setar essa função no evento "onclick" do componente ?

Comment: Ocultar a  tag "p" no css, e no jquery escutar o evento de click fazendo um "show"? @BrennoSegolim

Comment: Mas nesse caso teria que adicionar a tag "p" em todo os campos ou vários "span"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está removendo, porque você cadastrou o evento no seu `Form`.
E sempre que existir a mensagem, ao clicar em qualquer coisa ela será excluída.
Porque sua condição sempre será verdadeira.

Você pode cadastrar o evento `clique` diretamente no controle que está criando via `JQuery`.

```
// esse if adiciona a tag p com o conteúdo e atributos
if($(this).val().length <= 0){
  var p = $("<p>").text("Campo obrigatório").attr("class", "triangulo").addClass('caixa').attr("id","remover");

  p.click(function(e){
     $(this).remove();
  });

  var nome = $("form");
  nome.append(p);
}
});
```

Comment: Agora entendi, estava tentando escutar o evento pelo pai que é o form, tipo o event bublling no javascript. Você poderia me explicar o pq não precisar procurar o elemento "p"?

Comment: Porque como você já tem a referencia para ele no javascript o `this` dentro do evento `clique` que foi atribuído a ele, acaba sendo ele mesmo.